# PostScript on a Dymo labelwriter

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I'm trying to print a postscript file to a Dymo LabelWriter (tried a LabelWriter 450 and LabelWriter 330-Turbo), i'm getting it trough ok, but the margin seems to be way to high, 1/3 of the label isn't printable (see pic, the black square is supposed to cover the entire label over the width).

[image]

The label is 89mm on 39mm (so 252pt x 123pt)
I'm using a boundig box of `8 8 252 123` and the page orientation is set to portrait.

I even tested it with an eps-file generated from Gimp, it leaves the same area blank.

anyone has an idea why it isn't printing correctly?

EDIT:

The file can be viewed here : http://pastebin.com/c7YC5ftb

The command I use to print it on a Dymo LabelWriter is:

```
C:\ps\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sOutputFile="%%printer%%DYMO LabelWriter 450" -q "C:\ps\dymo.ps" -c quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, the printer wasn't set to accept this type of labels

If you ever have this problem go the advanced settings of your printer driver and set the label.

Answer (score 0):

Not without seeing the PostScript file, no. I don't see from the Dymo web site  that the printer accepts PostScript input, so how are you sending the PostScript file to it ?

Added in response to edits in the question.

Well its not absolutely clear to me what you expect this to look like.

Your original comment refers to a black square, but the PostScript doesn't contain a black square, it draws a rectangle with an aspect ratio of 20:1. You have set the media up to be wider than it is long (252,123) but you then use the Orientation to rotate the content by 270 degrees. Its true this is portrait, but upside down. If you want portrait why not just set the media to be portrait ?

Simply put the origin is the corner directly above your thumb in the photograph, and I think the long and short sides of the print are reversed with respect to the actual label.

Note that the BoundingBox comment is a *comment* and is ignored by the PostScript interpreter so changing it has no effect.

Perhaps if you could explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: KenS : I have updated to question to include both the command I use and the file I print.

Comment: if I leave the boundingbox away it's doesn't draw anything...
The definition "square" is indeed wrong, I'm trying to get the rectangle to go over the entire width so it doesn't stop where it does at the left side, but continues to the end of the label.

Comment: The first thing I would do is not print it, but use Ghostscript to view the result of rendering the PostScript. Until that looks the way you want it to, there's no point in trying to print it. Just use "gswin32 c:/ps/dymo.ps" to see what GS makes of your PostScript. In any event, you declare the media to be 252x123, and then draw a rectangle which is 200x10 so clearly its not going to cover the media. If you change the '10's in your program to 123 and the 200 to 252 then it will cover the media. I would also remove the spurious 20 dict begin which does nothing and the 0.2 setlinewidth.